# How to add an alias to the selected field?

Tags: sea-query

I want to join two tables with the `id` fields. Later, I want to access those fields using `row.get("field_name")` method from `sqlx`.

As far as two fields have the same name I want to add an alias to prevent the naming collision.

Here is my code snippet

```rs
let (query, values) = Query::select()
    .columns([
        (DbWorkingDay::Table, DbWorkingDay::Id) // How to add aliasl here?
    ])
    .columns([
        (DbAppointment::Table, DbAppointment::Id), // ...and here
    ])
    .from(DbWorkingDay::Table)
    .inner_join(DbAppointment::Table)
    ...
```

Currently, both of those fields return as `id`. Expected result should be `working_day_id` and `appointment_id`.

Any idea how to add aliases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to add alias to the column names by using [`sea_query::query::SelectStatement::expr_as`](https://docs.rs/sea-query/latest/sea_query/query/struct.SelectStatement.html#method.expr_as).

The working solution would look like this

```rs
let (query, values) = Query::select()
    .columns([
        (DbWorkingDay::Table, DbWorkingDay::Id)
    ])
    .columns([
        (DbAppointment::Table, DbAppointment::Id), 
    ])
+   .expr_as((DbWorkingDay::Table, DbWorkingDay::Id), Alias::new("working_day_id"))
+   .expr_as((DbAppointment::Table, DbAppointment::Id), Alias::new("appointment_id"))
    .from(DbWorkingDay::Table)
    .inner_join(DbAppointment::Table)
```